# How to derive the effective permeability for split ring resonator?

Tags: electromagnetism, refraction, metamaterials

in Pendry's 1999 paper "[Magnetism from Conductors and Enhanced Nonlinear Phenomena](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/798002)", he give the formula of effective relative permeability $mu_r$ of split ring resonator (SRR) which is one of the basic micro-structures of metamaterial, but how to derive this formula, especially where does the "3" comes from?

[image: Structure of SRR]

[image: formula of effective relative permeability]